# I want to the website rating to the list, how do I do this?

Tags: haskell

```
userRate :: Film -> Float
userRate (_,_,_,[],[]) = 0
userRate (_,_,_,likes,dislikes) = fromIntegral(length likes)/fromIntegral(length likes + length dislikes)* 100
```

--- function that rounds user ratings

```
websiteRating :: Film -> Int
websiteRating film = round(userRate (film))
```

-- function uses list comprehensions to filter films with website ratings 75 and above

```
rating:: [Film] -> [Film]
rating films = [ film | film <-films , websiteRating film >=75]
```

I have created a function that is giving me a list of films and only those films that are displayed with a website rating above 75, but I want to add the website rating next to the films

for example this is what is displayed

```
Title: Silence
Director: Martin Scorsese
Year:2016
Website Rating : 76



Title: The Terminal
Director: Steven Spielberg
Year:2004
Website Rating : 76%
```

I want to display the website rating in the list to how do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: How are you displaying the other things that are related to each film?  You have a function that gets the rating of a film, and you have a function that displays the attributes of a film that you care about.  Use the first in conjunction with the second?

Comment: in my Film type I have (String,String,Int,[Likes],[Dislikes]) . How do I add a function at the end of my tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this, whole result is a set of pairs comprising the film and the rating.

```
rating:: [Film] -> [(Film, Int)]
rating films = [ (film, rating) 
   | film <- films , let rating = websiteRating film, rating >=75 ]
```